# Find which explorer.exe is controlling the taskbar?

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I tend to leave my computer on for weeks at a time. The only issue I have with this is that the task bar flakes out after a number of days. Usually this takes the form of not rendering icons in the start menu. It can go as far as just not rendering anything in the start menu. Restarting the Explorer process works well to fix this in Windows 10.

Rather than manually trying to figure out which one of the `explorer.exe` tasks is handling the task bar and restarting it, I'd like to write a powershell script that does this.

How would I programmatically determine which instance of `explorer.exe` is currently responsible for the task bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly **more concise** alternative to [veefu's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48848131/45375):

Note: Similarly, no guarantees:
The method relies on the `.MainWindowTitle` property of the taskbar-owning File Explorer instance reflecting the *taskbar*'s window title, which happens to be *empty*, unlike the title of actual File Explorer windows - this appears to be the case on at least Windows 10 and Windows 7 (haven't tried others):

```
Get-Process explorer | ? MainWindowTitle -eq '' # returns taskbar-owning Explorer process
```

**If *other users* could be logged on** and you must limit the processes inspected to the current user's, run the following from an ***elevated* console**:

```
Get-Process -IncludeUserName explorer |
  ? MainWindowTitle -eq '' |
    ? UserName -eq (whoami)
```

---

**Robust, but more complex approach**:

Using `Add-Member -MemberDefinition`, you can define a helper type and method that finds the handle (HWND) of the process that owns the taskbar window, utilizing a P/Invoke signature to call a Windows API functions; note that you'll incur an on-demand compilation performance penalty the first time you call this in a session.<sup>Tip of the hat to [Klaidonis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2943191/klaidonis) for helping me simplify the code.</sup>

```
# Define a helper type and method for getting a window's handle
# (HWND) by its class name and title.
$helperType = Add-Type -PassThru -Name "WinApiHelper$PID" -MemberDefinition  @'
  [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
  public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);
'@

# Locate the explorer.exe process that created the taskbar,
# via window class "Shell_TrayHwnd" and an empty title.
Get-Process explorer | 
  ? MainWindowHandle -eq ($helperType::FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", ''))
```

---

As for **when *multiple* File Explorer processes may exist** (based on trial and error - do tell me if I got things wrong):

- If ***multiple users* are logged on interactively** (whether remotely or not), *each* such user may have one or more Explorer processes running, as described below.
- An interactively logged-on user has **at least *one* Explorer process**, which **owns the taskbar and the desktop** - it may or may not have actual File Explorer windows open; let's call it the ***Explorer shell process***.
- If File Explorer's **`Launch folder windows in a separate process`** view option is:

  - **OFF** (the default): all windows you create *interactively* are owned by the Explorer shell process - **no new process** is created.
  - **ON**: the ***first* window** you create *interactively* spawns ***one* new Explorer process** and all **subsequently opened windows are then owned by that *same* new process**.
  - In other words: If you only ever open File Explorer windows *interactively*, you either have *one* (`Launch folder windows in a separate process` OFF) or up to *two* (`Launch folder windows in a separate process` ON) Explorer processes.
    If you create Explorer windows *programmatically*, it is a different story - see next point.
- *Irrespective of the `Launch folder windows in a separate process` view setting*, new Explorer processes can be created *programmatically*:

  - For instance, a command such as `explorer /e,c:\` creates a new Explorer process every time.

Answer (score 5):

Note, the Folder Option 'Launch folder window in separate process' seems to be the setting that causes multiple explorer processes to be spawned. If this isn't set, it looks like there is only ever one Explorer.exe process.

It looks to me like every spawned explorer window beyond the first has a command-line including a '/factory' parameter, whereas the process that 'owns' the taskbar does not:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_process -Filter "name='Explorer.exe'" |
    Select-Object ProcessID,CommandLine
```

```
ProcessID CommandLine                                                 

--------- -----------                                                                       
     3140 C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /factory,{ceff45ee-c862-41de-aee2-a022c81eda92} -Embedding
     2068 C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe /factory,{682159d9-c321-47ca-b3f1-30e36b2ec8b9} -Embedding
    12164 "C:\WINDOWS\explorer.exe"
```

I tested by stopping the process that did have the taskbar, then spawning more explorer windows from an existing one. New explorer processes, having the /factory argument, did not re-create the taskbar.

Try finding explorer processes whose command-line don't contain `/factory`:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_process -Filter "name='Explorer.exe'" |
    Select-Object ProcessID,CommandLine |
    Where-Object Commandline -NotLike "*/factory*"
```

No guarantees, but it's a path of exploration for you.

Comment: This is promising. I do indeed have the "Launch folders in separate process" enabled.

Comment: Good answer; note, however, that additional Explorer processes may exist if other users are logged on as well; additionally, it's easy to create additional processes _programmatically_, such as with `explorer /e,c:\ `.

Answer (score 2):

When `explorer.exe` runs, if the taskbar isn't running, then that instance of `explorer.exe` runs the taskbar for that user.  It's then logical to conclude that the most likely process running the taskbar is the oldest `explorer.exe` process:

```
$CurrentProcessUser = Get-Process -PID $PID -IncludeUserName |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty UserName

$TaskBarProcess = Get-Process -Name explorer -IncludeUserName | 
    Where-Object UserName -eq $CurrentProcessUser | 
    Sort-Object -Property StartTime | 
    Select-Object -First 1
```

Is this guaranteed?  Probably not.  There's probably some knot of circumstances where this isn't the case.  But it's probably usually correct.

Comment: As I explained in my situation, I intend to restart that instance. This means your solution is only likely to be correct the first time the process needs to be found.

Comment: To be fair, you *could* track the process ID of the explorer instance your script created to “restart” the task bar the first time, and only restart that ID on subsequent runs.